# Does Ligo Lang run on OSX?

Tags: ligo

I tried installing ligo lang following the instructions here: https://ligolang.org/docs/intro/installation/

I have docker running, the bash install script runs fine, but I still get -bash: ligo: command not found

Comment: Having the same issue and the suggested solution isn't working. I'm getting docker: Error response from daemon: OCI runtime create failed: container_linux.go:367: starting container process caused: exec: "/root/ligo": stat /root/ligo: permission denied: unknown. Did anyone manage to solve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Put this snippet in a file named `ligo`

```
#!/bin/sh
docker run --user=`id -u` -v $PWD:$PWD -w $PWD ligolang/ligo:next "$@"
```

Then

```
chmod +x ligo
./ligo
```

does this work for you ?

Comment: I am having same issue, command given in documentation
https://ligolang.org/docs/intro/installation does pull image only but doesn't create container. I tried above solution, it creates container as well but container gets exit immediately with error 
Error invoking remote method 'docker-start-container': Error: (HTTP code 400) unexpected - OCI runtime create failed: container_linux.go:367: starting container process caused: exec: "/root/ligo": stat /root/ligo: permission denied: unknown